# ruby datamapper will not load

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-datamapper

I was trying to learn about the Sinatra ruby framework by following this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-recall-app-2/

however, after running the gem install and writing a simple sinatra server in test.rb like so:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'

get '/' do 
  "Hello, World!"
end
```

but when I run the command `ruby test.rb`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- datamapper (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from datamapper_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
glenn@ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Repositories/sandbox/sinatra$ ruby datamapper_test.rb 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- datamapper (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

it seems as though it cannot find the datamapper gem. how can I fix this?

**EDIT**: using ruby 1.9.2

**EDIT (again)**: (parital) output from `gem list`:

```
data_mapper (1.2.0)
data_objects (0.10.8)
datamapper (1.2.0)
devise (1.4.5)
directory_watcher (1.4.0)
dm-aggregates (1.2.0)
dm-constraints (1.2.0)
dm-core (1.2.0)
dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-migrations (1.2.0)
dm-serializer (1.2.1)
dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)
d    m-timestamps (1.2.0)
dm-transactions (1.2.0)
dm-types (1.2.1)
dm-validations (1.2.0)
do_sqlite3 (0.10.8)
sinatra (1.3.2, 1.2.6)
sqlite3 (1.3.5, 1.3.4)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
```

Comment: yea, right. Writing funny comments and then deleting them again. My last comment is a response to a deleted comment about requiring rubygems...

Comment: @three: My mistake. I use Ruby 1.8.7, so the first thing I noticed was that :) Anyway, it seems my answer is useless now, so I'll delete it.

Comment: :) Time to update for you! 1.9 is doing a great job.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to `require 'data_mapper'`, not `datamapper`.

Note there is a `datamapper` gem as well as a `data_mapper` gem, but they are the same thing, just different names. You need use `data_mapper` as the library name in both of them.

As far as I can tell `datamapper` is a straight copy of `data_mapper`:

```
$ diff -r data_mapper-1.2.0/ datamapper-1.2.0/
diff -r data_mapper-1.2.0/Rakefile datamapper-1.2.0/Rakefile
21c21
< GEM_NAME         = 'data_mapper'
---
> GEM_NAME         = 'datamapper'
```

Comment: Yes, `gem 'data_mapper'` worked for me. `datamapper` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`gem install datamapper` in your terminal might help :)
But you will also need a database and an adapter and you will want to use the gem somehow. Good luck and have fun with dm + sinatra!

Comment: i did run gem install datamapper, and have sqlite3 and the nessecary gems installed as well.